# Improve the speed of a BETWEEN search

Tags: postgresql

I have a query witch is selecting some data between two dates:

```
SELECT * FROM rk.p_reports
WHERE project_id = 1 AND engine_id = 1 AND type_id = 1 
  AND created_at::date BETWEEN now()::date - 14 AND now()::date
```

I have tried creating various indexes to speedup the queries but without any luck

First index: `project_id, engine_id, type_id, created_at ASC, created_at DESC`

Second index: `project_id, engine_id, type_id, created_at ASC` AND `project_id, engine_id, type_id, created_at DESC`

Third index: `project_id, engine_id, type_id, created_at ASC`

And other combinations, and non of the index was picked without turning enable_seqscan = off

At the moment it will take around 3 sec to return my rows, this partition has around 1.5 mil rows. I am using `Postgresql 9.4` on the DB server has 8 Gb ram and 6 cores.

Is there any way I can reduce this to under a sec?

```
Seq Scan on p_reports_1  (cost=0.00..57649.04 rows=4322 width=40) (actual time=614.221..696.583 rows=92607 loops=1)
Filter: ((project_id = 1) AND (engine_id = 1) AND (type_id = 1) AND ((created_at)::date <= (now())::date) AND ((created_at)::date >= ((now())::date - 14)))
Rows Removed by Filter: 1063344
Planning time: 0.200 ms
Execution time: 703.493 ms
```

Update, query modified as @ypercube sugested:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on p_reports_1  (cost=2952.28..17478.45 rows=89005 width=40) (actual time=17.485..34.569 rows=87712 loops=1)
Recheck Cond: ((project_id = 1) AND (engine_id = 1) AND (type_id = 1) AND (created_at >= ((now())::date - 14)) AND (created_at <= (now())::date))
Heap Blocks: exact=1180
 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on p_reports_1_asc_created_at  (cost=0.00..2930.03 rows=89005 width=0) (actual time=17.236..17.236 rows=87712 loops=1)
    Index Cond: ((project_id = 1) AND (engine_id = 1) AND (type_id = 1) AND (created_at >= ((now())::date - 14)) AND (created_at <= (now())::date))
Planning time: 0.319 ms
Execution time: 41.569 ms
```

Comment: You query takes 700ms (=0.7 seconds) not **3** seconds..

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But to actual see the data it takes around 3 sec i'm using navicat, so that what it tells me.

Comment: Then the time is lost while sending nearly 100.000 rows over the network and displaying that in your application. Btw: your actual and expected rows differ quite substantially. You should run `analyze rk.p_reports` to get your statistics up to date.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thx, please view my update, is anything better that I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the indexes are not chosen by the optimizer because they have the column `created_at` (which is a `timestamp`?) but the query is converting it to `date`.

I suggest you either create an index on `(project_id, engine_id, type_id, created_at::date)` or just keep the index on `(project_id, engine_id, type_id, created_at)` and change the condition to:

```
 AND created_at >= now()::date - 14 
 AND created_at < now()::date + 1
```

---

- You can use `current_date` instead of `now()::date`.
- I can't think of any situation where the `(project_id, engine_id, type_id, created_at ASC, created_at DESC)` would be useful. Drop this one.
- About the two other indexes, `(..., created_at ASC)` and `(..., created_at DESC)`, either one would be ok for the query (with the changed condition). I suggest you keep only one of them, unless you have other queries that need both.

Comment: Yes created_at is a timestamp, how do you suggest to create my index/indexes?, btw thx